# All Facebook messages from Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm building an application for my personal use that saves all my facebook messages in a database on my computer.

But I have a problem as it seems only few messages can be accessed through the Graph API.
I created a token with all the possible permissions.

When issuing a call:

```
/me/inbox
```

I get all the threads in my inbox but for some of them the `comments` field which contains the actual messages is missing. It's mostly for conversation with people that are not friend with me on facebook.

For those threads, when I try to get more information by `/<id_of_the_thread>`
I get an error (code 100) `Unsupported get request.` from the graph api.

Is it a normal behaviour of the API?
What am I missing here?

Don't hesitate if you know a better way of saving all my messages.

Answer (score 4):

Another, somewhat inferior, but much more accessible way of obtaining one's Facebook messages is by downloading a copy of your Facebook data through https://www.facebook.com/settings. This way you can download an archive with all your FB data, including your messages. They are however capped to 10,000 messages per conversation, and are all stored in one .htm file, which is not very practical if you want to do further operation on them.

Comment: Dealing with the same need. I already tried this aproach, it's an option of course. But the cons are:
The file will take some days to be sent by Facebook. the htm files containing your conversations lacks of attachments / images etc.

Answer (score 1):

No i think, we can't specified the Thread by using ID, but commonly i'm sorting the threads by its sender. CMIIW